# Подключение к базе данных mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Скажите, а можно ли этот метод, который подключается к БД с изменениями внести в `ActionListener` для кнопки

```
public static void connect(String mysql_login, String mysql_pass, String mysql_db) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + mysql_db, mysql_login, mysql_pass);
            System.out.println("The connection was successful.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
    }`
```

Код `ActionListner` для кнопки:

```
class Listik implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        form1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form1.setBounds(350,150,600,500);
        form1.add(menBar1);
        form1.revalidate();
        if (null == tf1.getText()||tf1.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Вы не ввели логин");
        }
        else if (null ==tf2.getText() || tf2.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Вы не ввели пароль");
        }
        else{
            form1.setVisible(true);
        }
```

Или это можно сделать как то по другому? И чтобы потом с формы можно было просматривать, добавлять, редактировать и искать данные в базе.

Comment: Метод можно внести в `ActionListener`. Можно сделать и по-другому. Всё зависит от ваших целей и возможностей

Comment: Эм, каждый раз инитить драйвер mysql, что простите? Достаточно одного раза подгрузить и использовать getConnection()